# Implement OrganizationUnit filter in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filter, aspnetboilerplate, ef-core-2.0

In ASP.NET Boilerplate, there are built-in Data Filters like Tenant filter, and we could use `SetTenantId` to enable querying specific `tenantId`.

As per the official document, it did not support custom `Filter` in EF Core, unlike EF 6.x.

I am wondering how to achieve a similar filter for `OrganizationUnitId` parameter.

This is what I have done so far:

1. Override `CreateFilterExpression`:

   ```
   protected override Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> CreateFilterExpression<TEntity>()
   {
       Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression = null;
       if (typeof(IMayHaveOrganizationUnit).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
       {
           Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> mayHaveOUFilter = e => ((IMayHaveOrganizationUnit)e).OrganizationUnitId == CurrentOrganizationUnitId || (((IMayHaveOrganizationUnit)e).OrganizationUnitId == CurrentOrganizationUnitId) == IsMayHaveOrganizationUnitFilterEnabled;
           expression = expression == null ? mayHaveOUFilter : CombineExpressions(expression, mayHaveOUFilter);
       }

       expression = expression == null ? base.CreateFilterExpression<TEntity>() : CombineExpressions(expression, base.CreateFilterExpression<TEntity>());

       return expression;
   }
   ```
2. I register the new filter by code below:

   ```
   Configuration.UnitOfWork.RegisterFilter("MayHaveOrganizationUnit", true);
   ```

But, how can I implement the code to set `OrganizationUnitId`?

`SetTenantId` is used to configure the `tenantId`, how could I configure `OrganizationUnitId` from `UnitOfWork`?

3. I try to inherit `ClaimsAbpSession` like below:

   ```
   public class CustomAbpSession : ClaimsAbpSession, ICustomAbpSession
   {
       private readonly IRepository<User, long> _userRepository;

       public CustomAbpSession(
           IRepository<User, long> userRepository,
           IPrincipalAccessor principalAccessor,
           IMultiTenancyConfig multiTenancy,
           ITenantResolver tenantResolver,
           IAmbientScopeProvider<SessionOverride> sessionOverrideScopeProvider)
           : base(principalAccessor, multiTenancy, tenantResolver, sessionOverrideScopeProvider)
       {
           _userRepository = userRepository;
       }

       public virtual long? OrganizationUnitId
       {
           get
           {
               if (UserId != null)
               {
                   var user = _userRepository.Get(UserId.Value);
                   return 1;
               }

               return null;
           }
       }

       public long? ImpersonatorOrganizationUnitId => throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
   ```

   ```
   protected virtual long? GetCurrentOrganizationUnitIdOrNull()
   {
       return 3; // ((ICustomAbpSession)AbpSession).OrganizationUnitId;
   }
   ```
4. Use code below to register custom `IAbpSession`:

   ```
   Configuration.ReplaceService(typeof(IAbpSession), () =>
   {
       IocManager.Register<IAbpSession, CustomAbpSession>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
   });
   ```

Usage:

```
public List<Product> GetAll()
{
    using (CurrentUnitOfWork.SetFilterParameter("MayHaveOrganizationUnit", "OrganizationUnitId", 2))
    {
        return _productRepositry.GetAll().ToList();
    }
}
```

But, it always return value from `OrganizationUnitId` in `CustomAbpSession`, this method `CurrentUnitOfWork.SetFilterParameter` did not set the value into filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't just a few lines of code.

Start with how `IMayHaveTenant` is filtered in [`CreateFilterExpression`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/6eccadb5d454f8f3d26bbd330f0d1ffd0455cbd6/src/Abp.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/AbpDbContext.cs#L176).

You can override [`ShouldFilterEntity`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/6eccadb5d454f8f3d26bbd330f0d1ffd0455cbd6/src/Abp.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/AbpDbContext.cs#L132) and `CreateFilterExpression` in your `DbContext`.

> `SetTenantId` is used to configure the tenantId, how could I configure `OrganizationUnitId` from `UnitOfWork`?

You can use the equivalent [`SetFilterParameter`](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Data-Filters#setting-filter-parameters) method.

> But, it always return value from `OrganizationUnitId` in `CustomAbpSession`, this method `CurrentUnitOfWork.SetFilterParameter` did not set the value into filter.

From `CurrentUnitOfWorkProvider.Current`, you can access [`Filters`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/6eccadb5d454f8f3d26bbd330f0d1ffd0455cbd6/src/Abp/Domain/Uow/UnitOfWorkBase.cs#L36):

```cs
protected virtual long? GetCurrentOrganizationUnitIdOrNull()
{
    if (CurrentUnitOfWorkProvider != null &&
        CurrentUnitOfWorkProvider.Current != null)
    {
        return CurrentUnitOfWorkProvider.Current
            .Filters.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FilterName == "MayHaveOrganizationUnit")?
            .FilterParameters["OrganizationUnitId"] as long?;
    }

    return ((ICustomAbpSession)AbpSession).OrganizationUnitId;
}
```