# How to implement Entity Framework Core data filters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filter, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

In my ASP.NET Zero application, I want to setup data filters by `CompanyId` value. 
So I read the documents [here](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Data-Filters) and the information provided on this support forum [thread](https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=10882&hilit=data%20filters).

In my EF Core project, I made the following change.

```
public override void PreInitialize()
{
    if (!SkipDbContextRegistration)
    {
        // ...

        Configuration.UnitOfWork.RegisterFilter("CompanyFilter", false);
    }
}
```

I then followed the pattern used for `IMustHaveTenant` data filter and applied the changes below into my DB context class:

```
protected int? CurrentCompanyId = null;
protected bool IsCompanyFilterEnabled => CurrentCompanyId != null && CurrentUnitOfWorkProvider?.Current?.IsFilterEnabled("CompanyFilter") == true;    

protected override bool ShouldFilterEntity<TEntity>(IMutableEntityType entityType)
{
    if (typeof(IHasCompany).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

protected override Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> CreateFilterExpression<TEntity>()
{
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression = null;

    if (typeof(IHasCompany).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
    {
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> companyFilter = e => ((IHasCompany)e).CompanyId == CurrentCompanyId || (((IHasCompany)e).CompanyId == CurrentCompanyId) == IsCompanyFilterEnabled;
        expression = expression == null ? companyFilter : CombineExpressions(expression, companyFilter);
    }
    return base.CreateFilterExpression<TEntity>();
}
```

Then, in my app service method where I wish to apply the filter, I added the code below.

```
public async Task<PagedResultDto<EmployeeListDto>> GetEmployees(GetEmployeeInput input)
{
    using (CurrentUnitOfWork.EnableFilter("CompanyFilter"))
    {
        using (CurrentUnitOfWork.SetFilterParameter("CompanyFilter", "CompanyId", GetCurrentUserCompany()))
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

In the DB context class, if I **hard code** a `CompanyId` value on the line below, the filter **works just fine**.

```
protected int? CurrentCompanyId = 123;
```

I will be honest, I do not fully understand the code that is being used in the `CreateFilterExpression` method in the DB context class. I borrowed this straight from the ABP GitHub repo code for `IMustHaveTenant` filter.

I have modified the ABP user "My Settings" modal to include `CompanyId`. This permits each user to be assigned to a company and thus the application should restrict all data by company for this user.

In my app service base class, I have a method named `GetCurrentUserCompany`. This method gets the current user's default company. This is the value that should be used on the data filter for company.

Questions:

- Do I need to set this company value in the DB context class?
- If yes, then how do I call an app service or repository method to get the `CompanyId` in this DB context class?

**Update:**
I added the code suggested by Aaron and its still not working. I'm testing with a user Id who has company 1 assigned. Yet when the data loads, it still showing them company 1 and 2.

[image: App service showing filter (line 71) has been set.]

[image: Debug cmd window showing company filter is set.]

When line 77 executes and does the GetAll call on the repository, its still showing all companies to the user.

**Oct 6 Update:**
The new code **works**, but only when the user has a company Id assigned. When the user does not have a company assigned, the error shown in the image below is thrown.
[image: DB context error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Do I need to set this company value in the Db context class?
> - If yes, then how do I call an app service or repository method to get the company Id in this DB context class?

No. Implement a getter in your `DbContext` class:

```
// using Abp.Collections.Extensions;

// protected int? CurrentCompanyId = null;
protected int? CurrentCompanyId => GetCurrentCompanyIdOrNull();

protected virtual int? GetCurrentCompanyIdOrNull()
{
    if (CurrentUnitOfWorkProvider != null &&
        CurrentUnitOfWorkProvider.Current != null)
    {
        return CurrentUnitOfWorkProvider.Current
            .Filters.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FilterName == "CompanyFilter")?
            .FilterParameters.GetOrDefault("CompanyId") as int?;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Return `expression` in your `CreateFilterExpression` method:

```
protected override Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> CreateFilterExpression<TEntity>()
{
    // Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression = null;
    var expression = base.CreateFilterExpression<TEntity>();

    if (typeof(IHasCompany).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
    {
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> companyFilter = e => ((IHasCompany)e).CompanyId == CurrentCompanyId || (((IHasCompany)e).CompanyId == CurrentCompanyId) == IsCompanyFilterEnabled;
        expression = expression == null ? companyFilter : CombineExpressions(expression, companyFilter);
    }

    // return base.CreateFilterExpression<TEntity>();
    return expression;
}
```

A similar question: [Implement OrganizationUnit filter in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49956072/implement-organizationunit-filter-in-asp-net-core)